# How to avoid resource overriding in Android ?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-library

I am working on Android Project, to avoid duplication of files I am using library project, but I have observed that "library project" is following overriding concept, First it will check resources files in Main Project if its not there then it will look in to library project.

for eg. My show splash screen code is in Library project so I have to incude splash screen image into Library project as well as in Main Project. I need to add resources for two time.

anyhow I can't publish library project but still I need to add resources such as slash screens, icon, etc in library project otherwise it will give an compile time error.

My all code is in Library project, so I need to provide all huge resources to it and new Main project also contains such different huge resources files. Its increasing my application size unnecessary.

Is there any way to avoid overriding resources files?

Can I share only common resources between projects? instead of all resource files.

How I can share only resources across the projects ?

Comment: could you explain why you have to include splash screen in your main project say your splash screen code is included in Library project

Comment: MY code is in Library project but I am using this Library project in several different projects. Like if I create a new project so that New Project should contains its own splash screen, icon or sound effects, in this case I cant use Library project resource files. So your answer is I have included Slash screen image file in Main project so when I run project it should show splash screen of Main project not from library project.